# Where DID you come from?/Where HAVE you come from?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between these 2 questions or both of them mean the same thing? How one should respond at each of them? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on context and tense they may not be interchangeable.

What is your country of citizenship? What place do you call home?  Only **do** works for those questions:

> Where do you come from?
>   --I come from a small town in Alaska.
>
> Where have you come from.  <sup>No</sup>

Where did you leave from to arrive here?  Who sent you? Either can be used:

> Where did you come from?
>
> --I came from the North Pole.
>
> Where have you come from?
>
> --I've come from the Office of Internal Affairs.

There is also the slight aspectual nuance of the past tense versus the present perfect there.  In certain circumstances the present perfect might be intended to signal that the answer to the question has some relevance to the present context. The answer could be relevant to the present context even if the question were posed using the simple past, but the language itself, the form of the verb, would not be any indication thereof in that case.